# Sending a custom email with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, email

I have a site called www.mystorkparty.com where you can build a registry for your baby-shower.
Now I want to add a link so a user can email there registry link to friends.

I can use html and create a link that opens there email program - but how do I put in a the specific registry URL in automatically. Or should I do an internal email setup rather and send from my the site itself.

Whats the best option?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the [mail_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-mail_to) helper for this. The `mail_to` helper allows you to specify a number of paramters such as `:subject` and `:cc` as optional arguments to pre-fil the link. You can also obfusicate the link using a number of options such as javascript or hex encoding.

An example link is similar to the link to method but looks like this:

```
mail_to "me@domain.com", "My email", :cc => "ccaddress@domain.com", :subject => "This is an example email"
```

This will create a `mailto:` link that will open the users default email client with the relevant values filled in.

Comment: Is there anyway to put ruby code in the subject and content part of the mail?

Comment: Sure just interpolate the string that you're passing in such as `:subject => "Url is #{@something}"`.